# Test Cafe - How to modify or inject data into a Response?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, hook, e2e-testing, testcafe

In TestCafe we have RequestHooks and RequestMocks. I would like my page to make an API call add for TestCafe to add one piece of data to the response that comes back.

What I have so far:

```js
import { RequestHook, RequestMock } from 'testcafe';

// option 1: RequestHook
class ModifyRequest extends RequestHook {
  constructor (requestFilterRules) {
    super(requestFilterRules, { includeBody: true });
  }
  async onRequest (event) {
    // ...
  }
  async onResponse (event) {
    const copy = JSON.parse(event.body.toString());

    copy.test = 'test';

    event.body = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(copy), 'utf8');
    // doesn't actually modify the response
  }
}

// option 2: RequestMock
export const modifyRequest = RequestMock()
  .onRequestTo(/processing/)
  .respond((req, res) => {
    console.log(res); // actual response not available
    res.setBody({
      data: 'original data here'
    });
  });
```

How do I actually make the API call and add data to the response?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, you want to mock only a part of the response. At this moment you cannot do this using the `RequestHooks` mechanism. `RequestMock` modifies a full response, `RequestHook` does not allow you to modify the response `body`.

Comment: thank you, I think inside RequestMock I can make a call using `axios`, but I don't really want to have to do that if I can avoid it.

Comment: Would be nice to see that option

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your RequestMock to your fixture as a hook:

```
fixture`<fixture-name>`
  .page(<url>)
  .requestHooks(modifyRequest);
```

Full example here: https://github.com/proustibat/xke-introduction-testcafe/blob/58eb6b51548ae1d9498c853ee8f8b748e5623218/e2e/index.js#L64

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with how to attach a request hook, but I wanted to know how to make the actual request and then modify the response before it makes it to the client.